# Get executed GCC/clang compiler commands in Eclipse CDT

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I'm working on an Eclipse plug-in that generates a [compilation database for clang.](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/JSONCompilationDatabase.html)

I've managed to load the managed configurations and obtained the names of the files to be compiled. However, I need to get the compiler (gcc, clang, vc, ...) commands determined by invoking the managed make system, as I need to save those commands into the compilation database.

Is there any way to plug into the CDT compilation process in order to access the compiler commands?

A little bit of background information: I've written my own builder plug-in that gets executed before the CDT builder. The plug-in itself isn't that spectacular. Nevertheless, it is capable of loading all build configurations and their associated toolchains that generate the executables, meaning I can leverage those.

The build configurations are stored in a map and can be accessed via the configuration name: `Map<String, List<IConfiguration>> configurations = new TreeMap<>();`

The delta visitor is a simplification of the one provided in the Eclipse PDE examples:

```
private class SampleDeltaVisitor implements IResourceDeltaVisitor
{
    private final CompilationDatabaseEditor editor;

    public SampleDeltaVisitor(CompilationDatabaseEditor editor)
    {
        this.editor = editor;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean visit(IResourceDelta delta) throws CoreException
    {
        IResource resource = delta.getResource();
        if ((resource.getFileExtension() != null) && (SUPPORTED_FILE_TYPES.contains(resource.getFileExtension())))
        {
            switch (delta.getKind())
            {
                case IResourceDelta.ADDED:
                    System.out.println("Adding " + resource.getName());
                    editor.addEntry(resource.getFullPath().toOSString(), "", resource.getFullPath().removeLastSegments(1).toOSString());
                    break;
                case IResourceDelta.REMOVED:
                    System.out.println("Removing " + resource.getName());
                    editor.removeEntry(resource.getFullPath().toOSString(), "", resource.getFullPath().removeLastSegments(1).toOSString());
                    break;
                case IResourceDelta.CHANGED:
                    System.out.println("Changing " + resource.getName());
                    editor.removeEntry(resource.getFullPath().toOSString(), "", resource.getFullPath().removeLastSegments(1).toOSString());
                    editor.addEntry(resource.getFullPath().toOSString(), "", resource.getFullPath().removeLastSegments(1).toOSString());
                    break;
            }
        }
        //return true to continue visiting children.
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem here is that CDT delegates compilation process to make so there is probably no way to figure out which commands are used except for parsing build log.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into the build log then. That's a pity, though.

Comment: You could use the `CDT GCC Build Output Parser` to get this information. [CDT bug 511851](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=511851#c33) could benefit from your work.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just use [Bear](https://github.com/rizsotto/Bear) by changing the build command from `make` to `bear make`?

Comment: If you really want to muck with CDT internals, I would suggest asking your question on the [CDT mailing list](https://accounts.eclipse.org/mailing-list/cdt-dev).